# Trouble understanding Blagouchine's extensions to the Malmsten integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$The great work of Blagouchine massively generalises the Malmsten integral. I am actually familiar with contour integration, but he consistently introduces results from other papers that I am unfamiliar with, so it feels disingenuous to take notes on a proof I can't understand.

I am interested in arriving at the following in a more "simple" manner:

> Let $a\ge0$ be real. Then: $$J(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}{\cosh(x)}\d x=2\pi\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{a}{2\pi}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{a}{2\pi}\right)}\right)+\pi\ln2\pi$$

As I mentioned, his derivation is not one that I am particularly keen to follow, but the similarity between this integral and Malmsten's integral made me hopeful one could be derived from the other.

> Malmsten's Integral: If $-\pi\lt\varphi\lt\pi$, then:$$I(\varphi)=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{x^2+2\cdot\cos(\varphi)x+1}\d x=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc(\varphi)\ln\left((2\pi)^{\varphi/\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\varphi}{2\pi}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\varphi}{2\pi}\right)}\right)$$

This I have seen a good proof of and am satisfied with.

Sadly I did not get very far with tackling $J$:

> $$J(a)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}{e^x+e^{-x}}\d x$$Which under the transformation $x\mapsto e^x$ becomes: $$J(a)=2\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(\ln^2(x)+a^2)}{x^2+1}\d x$$Which is *almost* equal to $2\cdot I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. We want the term inside the logarithm to be simply $\ln(x)$. For clarity, introduce $t$ a dummy variable. For $\ln^2(x)+a^2=\ln(t)$, one gets $t=e^{a^2}x^{\ln(x)}$, and$\d t=2e^{a^2}x^{\ln(x)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\d x$, and an expression for $x$ in terms of $t$ too ugly to type.

I do not see how to go any further.

I also do not see how to reverse engineer Blagouchine's closed form into an expression involving $I$ and $a$. It is similar to $I(\pi/2 + a)$, but not close enough.

Must I resign myself to researching his contour integration, or can this be done using Malmsten's integral as a first principle? If it can be done, I am not expecting the full proof, just an indication. Of course, if an answerer wants to derive it fully anyway for the joy of it, feel free!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fully agree with you that the generalising work of Iaroslav V. Blagouchine ([here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257381156_Rediscovery_of_Malmsten%27s_integrals_their_evaluation_by_contour_integration_methods_and_some_related_results)) allows to easily evaluate a very wide class of integral; particularly, integrals of the forms $\int_{-\infty}^\infty R(x)\ln(x^2+a^2) dx$, where $R(x)$ enjoys the symmetry $R(x)=R(x+2\pi i)$.

There are two general ways of evaluation:

- using the series approach (similar to that used by Carl Malmsten) - the detailed example of such evaluation for the similar integral you can find in [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-evaluate-int_-infty-infty-frac-log-x-2-1-cosh-x-1-dx)
- the contour integration

In my opinion, the contour integration provides the shortcut to the answer, saves time and allows to use the original symmetry of the problem. It is not complicated in fact and is based on three main points:

- $\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma(x)\,\Rightarrow\,\, \ln x=\ln\Gamma(x+1)-\ln\Gamma (x)$
- $\cosh(x+2\pi i)=\cosh(x)$
- $\Gamma(x)$ does not have zeros (and, therefore, $\ln\Gamma(x)$ does not have branch points) inside the chosen contour in the complex plane

Let's consider the integral
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}{\cosh x}dx=2\pi \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln((2\pi t)^2+a^2)}{\cosh 2\pi t}dt$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{2\ln2\pi}{\cosh2\pi t}dt+2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\big(t^2+\frac{a^2}{(2\pi)^2}\big)}{\cosh2\pi t}dt$$
$$=2\ln2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\cosh x}+2\pi\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)}{\cosh 2\pi t}dt=I_1+I_2$$
$$I_1=2\ln2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\cosh x}=2\ln2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^x\,dx}{e^{2x}+1}=\pi\ln2\pi$$
To evaluate $I_2$ we can write
$$\ln\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)=\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it+1\big)-\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)=\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-i(t+i)\big)-\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)$$
and present the second integral $I_2$, using also the property $\cosh(x+2\pi i)=\cosh(x)$,  in the form
$$I_2=2\pi\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)}{\cosh 2\pi t}dt=-2\pi\Re\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-it\big)}{\cosh 2\pi t}dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-i(t+i)\big)}{\cosh 2\pi (t+i)}dt\bigg)$$
But we can see that the expression in the parentheses is the integral of the function $\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-iz\big)}{\cosh 2\pi z}$ along the following contour:

[image]

To close the contour we have to add the paths $[1]$ and $[2]$ (it can be shown that integrals along these paths $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$).
We have two simple poles inside the contour; therefore
$$I_2=-2\pi\,\Re\oint\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-iz\big)}{\cosh 2\pi z}dz=-2\pi\,\Re\Big(2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{\binom{z= i/4}{z=3 i/4}}\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-iz\big)}{\cosh 2\pi z}\Big)$$
To evaluate the residues we notice (for example, for $z=\frac{i}{4}+\epsilon; \,\epsilon\to0$)
$$\frac{1}{\cosh2\pi (\frac{i}{4}+\epsilon)}=\frac{2}{i(e^{2\pi\epsilon}-e^{-2\pi\epsilon})}\to\frac{1}{2\pi i\epsilon}$$
$$I_2=-2\pi\,\Re\Big(2\pi i\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-i\frac{i}{4}\big)}{2\pi i}-2\pi i\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}-i\frac{3i}{4}\big)}{2\pi i}\Big)=2\pi\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}+\frac{3}{4}\big)}{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{4}\big)}$$
Taking all together,
$$I(a)=I_1+I_2=\pi\ln2\pi+2\pi\frac{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}+\frac{3}{4}\big)}{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{a}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{4}\big)}$$

Comment: It's one of my favorite papers, but it's erroneously stated in the paper that the [log gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html) has no branch points.  Fortunately, the results are still valid since the branch cut for $\ln \Gamma \left(\frac{z}{2\pi i}+ \alpha \right), \, \alpha >0$, is entirely in the lower half-plane.

Comment: @Random Variable Yes, you are right

Comment: Thank you for this. I definitely found this easier to read than Blagouchine’s work. I have just two quibbles; I’m not sure from where you derived: $$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$I’m also unsure how you changed bounds in that integral from $[0,\infty]\to[-\infty,\infty]$. I think I buy your argument for the residues, using the cosh addition formulae, but I’m unsure on my justification for the last step: $$e^{2\pi\epsilon}-e^{-2\pi\epsilon}=4\pi\epsilon+\frac{16(\pi\epsilon)^3}{6}+\cdots\to4\pi\epsilon$$Via Maclaurin series. Is this right?

Comment: @RandomVariable As far as I understand it, the logarithm is cut whenever the argument extends beyond an interval $(2\pi k-\pi,2\pi k+\pi]$. How does one know when the Gamma function does this? I have no idea how you know this happens in the lower half plane only

Comment: @FShrike, I agree with you. It also took time for me to go through Blagouchine’s finding. IMHO, it can be explained easier, so I tried :). Regarding your first question: the integrand is even, therefore $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\cosh x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\,dx}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d(e^x)}{e^{2x}+1}=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @FShrike, regarding finding residues - this is correct, via Maclaurin series at $\epsilon\to0$

Comment: Excellent answer. +1. I just now need to study the asymptotic analysis which references a gazillion other papers...

Comment: @FShrike  There's a difference between the log gamma function and the logarithm of the gamma function. The log gamma function $\ln \Gamma(z)$ has a single branch cut  along the negative real axis. It's explained briefly in that MathWorld article I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @FShrike  There is no restriction on how large the imaginary part of the log gamma function can be, which can be seen from from the definition $\log \Gamma(z) = - \gamma z -\ln z + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{k} - \ln(1+ \frac{z}{k})\right) $.

Comment: @RandomVariable So that definition yields somehow a super nice logarithm with only one cut?

Comment: @FShrike   The log gamma function is the above definition if you use the principal branch of the logarithm for the $\ln$ terms.  The definition can be derived from Weierstrass's infinite product definition of the gamma function.

Comment: @FShrike So yes, a single branch cut along the negative real axis is all that's needed since the branch cut for the $\ln z$ term is on $(-\infty, 0]$, and the branch cut for each $\ln \left(1+ \frac{z}{k} \right), k \ge 1$, term is on $(-\infty, -k]$.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you very much

Comment: I’ve understood more of his work now. I have a quibble I’d like to ask you: suppose I had no interest in the principal values and similar regularisations of divergent integrals. Then his identity: (excluding the pseudo rigorous “poles on the contour” part)$$\int_0^\infty R(e^x)-R(e^{-x})\,dx=4\Re\left\{\sum\mathrm{Res}\left[R(e^z)\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2\pi i}\right)\right]\right\}$$Is a concerning one. If $R$ does not go to zero sufficiently fast as $z$ does, then we have a singularity at $z=0$ *on* the contour. Does that mean this identity is at best half-rigorous, if $R$ isnt suitable?

Comment: Hello everyone! Thank you for your interest in my work on Malmsten's integrals. Just would like to remark (@RandomVariable @Svyatoslav) that regarding the branch points of the log-gamma function, in my paper, p.780->p.42, it is stated that "As a consequence, $\ln\Gamma(z)$ has no branch points except at poles of $\Gamma(z)$". 
P.S. The proofs of my paper contained a huge number of misprints in formulas and in many places the original text was modified. Taking into account a very limited amount of time for the correction of the proofs, I decided to focus my attention only on formulas.

Comment: Later, in 2017, I published a list of errata related to some of the misprints I found in the text and this list is merged to the original file. The link provided by @Svyatoslav (thanks!) precisely refers to the paper with the list of errata.

Comment: @Iaroslav Blagouchine, it's my pleasure to meet you in person :). I really enjoy the method you developed, and stay convinced that this approach - being the elegant shortcut in many cases - should be used more widely. In my opinion, this is not just an exotic method, but rather a very powerful practical tool to handle a wide class of integrals.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much for your very kind comment and for your appreciation of my work! Of course, the contour integration approach for such a kind of integrals is very powerful and may be used in many other situation as well. Actually, I am currently working on other extensions, which may be useful for several important and still unsolved problems. It is also very unfortunate that this method is disappearing more and more from the university curriculum.

Comment: @Iaroslav Blagouchine I would be more than happy to get the link and study new extensions of the method - as soon as they were ready :) In my opinion, there is no more joy in live than studying an elegant piece of mathematics.

Comment: @IaroslavBlagouchine When I was in college about 10 years ago, real analysis was a required class but complex analysis wasn't.  Most applied math majors graduated without taking a complex analysis class.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Well, it took me a year and a half to work on Malmsten's integrals, and I think my current work will take even more time. But as soon as it's ready, I'll let you know. By the way, if you like contour integration methods, especially unusual applications, you might also like this book: 
Mitrinovic and Keckic - The Cauchy method of residues. Theory and applications (1984)

Comment: @RandomVariable Yes, that's exactly what I was talking about...

Comment: @Iaroslav Blagouchine Thank you very much, and thank you also for your recommendation regarding interesting applications of complex integration.